# Strange issue with Apache common collection

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons

I am not sure what might be the cause of this issue but i am facing it since morning and seems like i am doing something wrong or i have done something wrong with my Eclipse IDE

i have included Apache commom collection is my project using maven as follow

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Depedency is getting included correctly, but when i am trying to use following method of collection util

```
MapUtils.isEmpty(java.util.Map map) 
or
MapUtils.isNotEmpty(java.util.Map map)
```

They are not being shown in the editor and only method i can see under MapUtil is

```
invertMap(java.util.Map map)
```

i check the import statement in Eclipse and its

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils;
```

Not sure where things are going wrong as i have used above utility method number of times, do any one have any clue

Comment: May be you have wrong version of jars in classpath?

Comment: @Nambari:can you plz describe which wrong version? is there any specific information as only those methods are not there rest of them is visible to me.

Comment: Refresh your eclipse project using mvn eclipse:eclipse and open the project again. You will have the right dependency then.

Comment: @SureshKoya i already done that, also as i mentioned jar is there only issue i am facing method are not there

Comment: You were looking in the wrong class. You should look into CollectionUtils.isEmpty

Comment: Are you sure it's 3.2.1 you are using? Check from where the import is comming from, you maybe having some conflict, because one of your libs is importing another version of apache.commons.

Try importing "org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils" and see if there's still a problem.

Comment: @RalfHoppen:I guess you have pointed correctly, i just missed to check this

Comment: @RalfHoppen:can you post your comment, that was the issue, wrong jar was getting refrenced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it's 3.2.1 you are using? Check from where the import is comming from. You maybe having some conflict, because one of your libs is importing another version of apache.commons.

Try importing "org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils" and see if there's still a problem.

Comment: this was the exact issue, i was thinking about version 3.2.1 while actually it was being included as 3.0 and those methods were not part of that.Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

Your import is correct. CollectionUtils ( http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html ) has methods

```
CollectionUtils.isEmpty(java.util.Map map) 
CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(java.util.Map map)
```

You are just looking int the wrong class MapUtils.

Comment: i can only find `isEmpty(java.util.Collection)` in `CollectionUtils` [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html)

Comment: It is there since 3.2 and I added a link to the javadoc in my answer.